# Using pymongo to overwrite a document when it already exist just by using `insert`

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am using `pymongo` to insert documents that I fetched from somewhere regularly.

This could be adding a new element or replacing documents that already exist in my database.

Right now, I do

```
db.test.insert({
    'username': 'test',
    'data': [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
})
```

which inserts a document successfully.

I know there is a function called `replace_one` but does not serve my purpose because I am regularly running this script and there could be something to be updated and something new, so I would just use insert and update whenever the document with the same `username` already exist.

How can I just use `insert` to do this, or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `update_one` and passing `upsert=true` parameter to it. According to [the documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one):

> update_one(filter, update, upsert=False,
>   bypass_document_validation=False, collation=None, array_filters=None,
>   session=None)
>
> - filter: A query that matches the document to update.
> - update: The modifications to apply.
> - upsert (optional): If True, perform an insert if no documents match the filter.

So in your case it would be:

```
db.test.update_one(
  {'username': 'test'},
  ,{
    'username': 'test',
    'data': [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
  },
  upsert=True
)
```

First, it will try to find a document with that username and update it and if that was unsuccessful it will create one.